# Inserting record in two table ? In Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

In Sql server, can we insert one record in two temporary table at a time.

```
 insert into #TmpTAApproval 
 insert into #TmpFinal
 select reqid,applicationid from Mytable
```

How can we write, is this possible ? thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `OUTPUT ... INTO` the second table.

[image: Execution Plan]

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTest1
  (
     FirstCol INT
  );

CREATE TABLE #tmpTest2
  (
     FirstCol INT
  );

INSERT INTO #tmpTest1
     OUTPUT inserted.FirstCol
INTO #tmpTest2
SELECT 1;

SELECT *
  FROM #tmpTest1;

SELECT *
  FROM #tmpTest2;

DROP TABLE #tmpTest1;

DROP TABLE #tmpTest2;
```